# Why I'm getting error response from server when trying to upload file using HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, http-request

I'm trying to upload file to server(not mine) i think i did exactly what it needs but please can somebody correct me if am i doing wrong

**here is the API**

```
POST https://i cant share the URL HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data;
boundary=----------------------------8d19a412e59ea7e
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.143 Safari/537.36
Content-Length: 567460
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive
------------------------------8d19a412e59ea7e
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"; filename="report.xml"
Content-Type: application/xml
```

**my request**

```
private String uploadFile(String sourceFile,url)
        throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "--------------------------8d19a412e59ea7e";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="
        + boundary);
    conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", "");

    dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

    dos.writeBytes(boundary + lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=fileName;fileName=" + sourceFile+ boundary);

    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

    // create a buffer of maximum size
    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    while (bytesRead > 0) {

        dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

    }

    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

    // Responses from the server (code and message)

    String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
    int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
        (conn.getInputStream())));
    String inputLine = null;
    while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(inputLine);
    return serverResponseMessage;
}
```

Comment: It is not really clear what your problem ist. What error message do you get?

Comment: Im getting invalid upload file,, status code 200 but the responsw which i got is invalid file upload i have no idea why, are all the headers correct as api mentions?

Comment: Maybe you should fix your post. Your code is for sure not correct (e. g. `uploadFile(String sourceFile,url)`. And it doesn't look like what you will generate looks like what you wrote before will be generated. Besides that it doesn't look like the correct thing to be generated. Maybe you should use Apache Commons HttpClient instead of doing the low-level work yourself.

Comment: The file is existing on the storage it's file's path

Comment: I want to check if the headers are correct